# how to use clang compile c file with math.h?

Tags: c, ubuntu, clang, math.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%.81f\n", 1+2*sqrt(3)/(5-0.1));
    return 0;
}
```

output:
/tmp/a4-4oU730.o: In function `main':
a4.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to`sqrt'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If you google the error message, several thousands of solutions come up.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-lm` for libm for math to your build command.  That said, your code works fine for me using clang 4.1 on Mac OS.